# SQL Error: -1, SQLState: 08000 not flushing record

Tags: java, grails, mariadb, tomcat8

Technical background: Groovy 2.5.6 using Java 8. MariaDb database.

Background: I have a report system in place. Different Reports are added to a database table. A job executes every 15 minutes and puts a report into a "In progress" state from a "New" state. Then once the job successfully executes the report is updated to a "Done" state. If any exceptions occur the report will put into a "Error" state.

The problem is that once the job executes the report fails to save. In the logs I can see I get a `SQL Error: -1, SQLState: 08000` and `(conn=64796) Socket error`. This indicated to me that there is a connection issue with the database. This is followed with `SQL Error: 1220, SQLState: 08000`.

There is a problem with the database connection, which has already been closed. The application is failing to generate a report and update a record.

I put the report again in a "New" state and let the job re-run. The same issue occured again. So I was able to replicate it. I do not really have a clear method to follow to troubleshoot.

How do I resolve this error? Is this related to Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

Did this just started to occur? How were you keeping the connection alive before? One way to do that is the following:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "myuser"
    password = "mypassword"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase"
    properties {
        // Set validation query to keep connection alive
        validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = true
        testOnReturn = false
        validationInterval = 30000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
    }
}
```

In this example, the validationQuery is set to "SELECT 1", which is a simple query that will always return a result. This query will be executed every 30 seconds (as specified by validationInterval) to ensure that the connection is still alive.

Comment: This only occurred when a "Month-end" report is generated containing a lot of data. I can confirm that `validationQuery = "SELECT 1"` was already present in my application. I will add the suggested ` validationInterval = 30000` and test. 

Before this became an issue we used the following properties:         
        maxIdle=100
        maxWait=60000
        maxActive=400
        validationQueryTimeout= 3

Comment: It seems like have the right configurations. Try adding a value for the intervals and see if that would work. Also, I am assuming that in your title you meant Grails 2.5.6 and not Groovy 2.5.6, correct?